# does watson assistant know if there is null response from user?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I have created a chatbot in Watson assistant and I need a condition where if there the user goes silent for 10 seconds I continue the conversation. is there a way for Watson to know if there is no response (null response)?
Also, does Watson know if the user clicked on a link? is clicking on a link considered a response in Watson?

Answer (score 2):

Watson Assistant does not know if a user hasn't sent back a response,
you can do one of the following:

if you are using WA web chat channel, use the [events](https://web-chat.global.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/docs.html?to=api-events) provided to control the flow. You can set a timer via `pre:recieve` and reset it if the user did send a message via `pre:send`.
if there is a timeout send a message [via send operation](https://web-chat.global.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/docs.html?to=api-instance-methods#send).

Alternatively, if you plan on supporting more than just a web chat channel (e.g. facebook, phone, whatsapp, etc.), you are better off implementing the same logic in a [Post Message webhook](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-webhook-post) and . Essentially, make your code keep a timer in the Post message and if a user send a reply, turn the timer off in [a Pre Message webhook](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-webhook-pre)